# PSTricks -> How can I compile a graph/figure to obtain an PNG/JPG with background transparent?

Tags: pstricks, backgrounds, transparency, png, jpeg

How to obtain this graph in a PNG/GIF/JPG graph with transparent background?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor} % colores por nombres y tablas. dddd%

\usepackage{datetime}
\settimeformat{ampmtime}

\usepackage{hyperref} %Dudo si este paquete puede dar error al compilar con LATEX (no PDFLATEX)
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue}


\headheight=15pt  %/ MARGENES y otros

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%--------   Paquetes para uso con PSTricks  -----------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{pstricks}
% -------- Paquetes de pst-all \usepackage{pst-all}   paquete pstricks para las figuras en postcript
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-3d}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{multido}
% ---- Fin Paquetes de pst-all
\usepackage{pst-fr3d}               % paquete pstricks para las figuras en postcript
\usepackage{pst-infixplot,pst-math} % paquete pstricks para las figuras en postcript
%%%%%   Paquetes para definir los "ladillos" de la parte superior de las páginas, los capítulos, las secciones y más cosas.
%%%%% La explicación de cómo se hace todo esto viene en las instrucciones que están incluidas en la instalacion.
\usepackage[clearempty,explicit,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%%%% Paquete para hacer los gráficos.   % OJO.- En alguna compilación me daba incompatibilidad de esta opción dvips con la clase article %
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}  % OJO.- HE QUITADO [dvips] antes de {graphicx} porque me daba error , y me pedía poner [dvips] en la clase principal, pero aparecía atenuado en article, como si no aceptase esta opción. Cargar despues de paquetes PSTricks
%--------   Fin Paquetes para uso con PSTricks  -------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{graphicx}    % paquete para insertar gráficos
\usepackage{epstopdf}    % para que funcioneen los eps con pdflatex
\usepackage{multicol}    % para incluir columnas multiples

\usepackage{marginnote}  % para crear notas al margen

\usepackage{mathpazo}    % para usar la fuente MathPAzo que me gusta más, yse lee bien.

\usepackage{fix-cm}  
\usepackage{anyfontsize} %

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   % Paquete para cabeceras y pies en cada página.
\pagestyle{fancy}       % seleccionamos un estilo

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.- }   % personalizado a mi gusto los itemize.

\graphicspath{{G:/}{G:/Rafa/TEX Arquivos/}}

\settimeformat{ampmtime} % para incrustar fecha y hora en los documentos.

\spanishdecimal{.}       % Para usar el punto decimal, y no confundirlo con las comas.

% ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// %
%\cfoot{\includegraphics[width=11cm]{heado2}} % imagen centro del pie
\lhead{M.I.} % texto izquierda de la cabecera
%\chead{\today \;-\;  \currenttime } % texto centro de la cabecera
\rhead{Right Header} % número de página a la derecha
% - - -  - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - %
\lfoot{{\gray{\footnotesize Compilado: \today \;-\;  \currenttime}}} % texto izquierda del pie
\rfoot{Página \thepage}
% texto derecha del pie
\cfoot{} % texto central del pie
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} % grosor de la línea de la cabecera
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} % grosor de la línea del pie
% ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// %
%\title{Foro }
%\author{Rafa S.F.}
%\date{\today}
% //////////////////////////////////////////////// %

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   Figura 2.1
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\psset{unit=.6cm,linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black,nodesep=3pt,arrowscale=1.3,arrows=->,arrowsize=4pt}\small
 \begin{pspicture}*(-.5,0)(9.5,9.5)
\psframe[fillcolor=white,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-.5,0)(9.5,9.5)

\rput(1,3){$\circlenode{A}{\textcolor{blue}{a}}$}
\rput(3,6){$\circlenode{B}{\textcolor{blue}{b}}$}
\rput(5,1){$\circlenode{C}{\textcolor{blue}{c}}$}
%
\ncline{->}{A}{B}\naput{\small $43$}
\ncarc[arcangleB=300]{->}{C}{B}\naput{\small $12$}
%
\ncarc{->}{C}{A}\naput{\small $23$}

%


 \end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\caption{prueba}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: By design, jpeg doesn't support transparency.

Comment: @AlexG OK, you´re right, but PNG and GIF, yes. I know that GIF is a commercial format, so i prefer PNG.

Comment: Why should it be transparent? Without using the environment `pspicture` you can draw over any object.

Comment: @MikaIke: The patents on GIF are long expired; GIF is free.

Comment: @Herbert: I guess he wants to use it in a web page, perhaps with a wall paper behind.

Comment: @Herbert I want a transparent background to put graphs in images/pictures in a Design software. I use Adobe Fireworks CS6.

Comment: @Herbert It´s for put graphs in my Curriculum Vitae :-) and any other graphs, created with PSTricks.

Comment: But in other order of things to create a wallpaper as @AlexG said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using ImageMagick:

```
convert -density 300x300 simplenetwork02_stack.pdf -transparent white simplenetwork02_stack.png
```

To have just the PSTricks graphic as output, add

```
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
```

to the preamble. You may want to adjust the `pspicture` size to get a tightly boxed graphic:

```
\begin{pspicture}*(0,0)(6,7)
%\psframe[fillcolor=white,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-.5,0)(7.5,7.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! I like your solution.

Where i shoul type    -convert density.....

I usually click the PDFLATEX/xelatex icon, and obtain de PDF.
 http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/4679/snap2163.png

Comment: @MikaIke: ImageMagick is a separate piece of software (independend from TeX), consisting of a number of commandline tools. You can download it from http://www.imagemagick.org. `convert` is run on the ready PDF file that was output by `xelatex` or `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`.

Comment: \AlexG ok, i´m trying.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded imagemagick, but I don´t have a visual compiler.
I like your solution, and I don´t know to abuse but... ¿Do you know about any other software to do this? I´m trying to install imagemagick,.. (windows).. but seems dificult.

Comment: As I see that you control the situation :-) ...  Any off-topic... I compile with Xelatex to can obtain the PSTricks picture, but it seems a little slow.   What is the best option in your opinion?

Comment: For installation on Windows, you can download ImageMagick as a [precompiled binary](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows). Thus, no compiler required. For compiling PSTricks code, I'd chose the traditional `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` route (unless you want to use non-standard fonts).

Comment: \AlexG Yes, finally ImageMagick runs well on my windows vista.
Now I´m doing what you tell me.
1:Latex 2:DVI->PS  3:PS->PDF. What I can´t know to do now, is automatize the 3 steps, in only one automatically.
Thank you.

Comment: Via a `.bat` script, maybe?

Comment: this also works for documents with more than one graph. Had created several graphs in `standalone` class with pstricks (all of different size) and now have many beautiful `.png`s with a single line of code.

Answer (score 3):

By default the canvas provided by `pspicture` is transparent. If you fill it with other colors such as `psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]...` then the canvas is no longer transparent.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}% set border=0pt if you don't want to have borders.
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](3,3)
    \pscircle(1.5,1.5){1}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile the code above to get a PDF output. And then use ImageMagick to convert it to PNG with transparency as follows.

```
convert -density 100 -alpha on filename.pdf filename.png
```

The output is

> [image]

The quote markdown is used here to show the transparency effect clearly. The background looks yellowish that proves that it is really transparent!

### Remarks:

`-alpha` has 3 mutual-exclusive options: `on` (enabling transparency), `off` (disabling transparency with bad output), and `remove` (removing transparency with good output).

### Warning:

The `-transparent` option explained and suggested by AlexG does not produce a good output as follows.

The following is the input. The red region will be converted to be transparent.

[image]

After conversion with `convert -density 300 -transparent red in.pdf out.png`, the output is as follows.

[image]

There are still red pixels on the boundaries of the red region. Are you satisfied with it? I don't.

Comment: I like your response. I downloaded ImageMagick, but It seems any ocmplicated. I have no Visual Studio to compile... and I haven´t benn capable to execute de "convert ...." command. Could you help me?

Comment: @MikaIke: You should download the binary rather than the source code. I will give you the correct link to download the binary. Please wait in a couple of miliseconds.

Comment: @MikaIke: It is the link to download the binary for Windows: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Yes... i prefer a clean boundarie. Thank you very much :-)) I´m impresed. Do you recomend me any web with fantastic scientifics graphs/wallpapers?

Comment: jajaja :-) please,... only 1 milisecond jajaja :-))))

Comment: @clic-me I have to redownload , becuse i try with any of that links but... Windows tell me "The Setup files are corrupted" (after 3 downloads, of diferentes links). I´m trying later.

Comment: I install imagemagick and works well till the final moment... I have a system error "The program crash down!"
http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3688/snap2171.png
So, i retry when I install a new system,... or I try to find any other solution or software (I like fireworks CS6).
Thank you very much.

Comment: YES., @click-me FANTISTIC, ALL WORKS FANTACTICLY :-).
Thanks.
The question is closed.

Comment: @MikaIke: You should close this question by accepting either my answer or AlexG's answer. There is a check mark button below the down vote button. Just click the check mark button to finalize your case. :-)