# What dimensions and how to insert an image as a cover?

Tags: pstricks, covers

I viewed any message but I don´t reach the solution.

I want to make an imge to use as cover for my final job.

What dimension do you recommend? in pixels(better) or cm?  or   What proportions? to the image.

and when I have the cover.jpg.

How can I insert as the 1st page in my job?, preferly without margins.
I usually use pstricks, not tikz

(I know that this message can be dislike for any of you, so... If it´s neccesary... I delete it.)

Comment: Do you need to use a jpg? If you could use a vector graphic you wouldn't get problems scaling the image.

Comment: @JuriRobl Yes, I prefer JPG/PNG, because I use Adobe FireWorks CS6, and want to modify and use many images..

Comment: In this kind of things I remember any fantastics comments to make transparent images from LATEX vectorials images: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117897/pstricks-how-can-i-compile-a-graph-figure-to-obtain-an-png-jpg-with-backgroun/117908?noredirect=1#comment262214_117908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
You can use  bmp2eps to convert from BMP/GIF/PNG/JPEG/PNM/TGA to PS/EPS. Now you can input the picture.eps with \includegraphics*[scale=...]{picture.eps} with \usepackage{graphicx}

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
pagecolor=blue, menucolor=blue, linkcolor=blue,
bookmarksopen=true, % Anzeige aller Ebenen
bookmarksnumbered=true, % Anzeige der Abschnittsnummern
pdfstartpage={}, % Startseite
pdfstartview={FitH}, % Legt die Anzeigegröße fest
pdftitle = {Mathematik in Klasse 12}, 
pdfsubject = {Unterrichtsmaterial},
pdfauthor = {Söll, Thomas} }

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
\includegraphics*[scale=1.1]{tiger.eps}
}}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.9cm}%
\footskip=8mm
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.9cm} \textheight26.5cm \textwidth18.0cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Test}
\rhead{Geometrie}
\rfoot{\makebox[0mm][l]{\hspace*{-5mm}\setlength\fboxsep{3pt}\fcolorbox{black!90}{black!90}{\makebox[75pt]{\hfill%
\textcolor{cyan!20}{Seite~\thepage \hspace*{1.4cm}}}}}}
\cfoot{}

\parindent0pt
\parskip4pt



\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Titelseite}{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{3.5cm} \DeclareFixedFont{\Rm}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{2mm}
\psset{shadow=true,blur=true,shadowsize=10pt,blurradius=5pt,blurbg=blue!10}
\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,3.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=blue,slopeend=magenta} \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\pscharpath{\RM MATHE}}
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,3.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=black!80!green!60,slopeend=yellow} \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\pscharpath{\RM Oberstufe}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,4.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=magenta,slopeend=blue} \rput(0.5\linewidth,1.75cm){\pscharpath{\RM Kompakt}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-3cm)(\linewidth,4)
\DeclareFixedFont{\SF}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{4.5cm}%
\psset{linestyle=none,linecolor=red,linewidth=0pt}
 \pstextpath[l](-1ex,-1ex){\pscustom{%
\psplot[plotpoints=200,linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=red,linestyle=none]{0}{16}%
{x 180 mul 3.1415926 div cos 2 mul 1 add}%
 }}{%
\color{blue} Ich bin ein Sinus!  Nein, ein Komplementi Sinus? Also ein Tangens bin ich sicher nicht und auch
kein Schaubild einer e-Funktion, soviel ist sicher. Hi Hi Hi Am besten ich schau mal im entsprechenden
Kapitel nach. sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder
cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus?
}
\end{pspicture}


 Thomas Söll %\index[name]{Söll, Thomas}\index[name]{Ossig, Uli}\index[name]{Söll, Anna}
 \vspace*{1cm} \\
 Rhön-Gymnasium-Gymnasium \\
 in \\
 Bad Neustadt

\Acrobatmenu{GeneralInfo}{\fbox{DokumentInfo}}

 \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

Hier steht noch immer der gleiche Text, aber jetzt auf der zweiten Seite.

\end{document}

\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
pagecolor=blue, menucolor=blue, linkcolor=blue,
bookmarksopen=true, % Anzeige aller Ebenen
bookmarksnumbered=true, % Anzeige der Abschnittsnummern
pdfstartpage={}, % Startseite
pdfstartview={FitH}, % Legt die Anzeigegröße fest
pdftitle = {Mathematik in Klasse 12},
pdfsubject = {Unterrichtsmaterial},
pdfauthor = {Söll, Thomas} }

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
\psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradmidpoint=0.9,gradend=cyan!30!black!20,gradbegin=black!10,linewidth=0pt](0.7,0)(21,29.8)
%\psline[linecolor=yellow,linewidth=1.5pt](20.7,29.8)(20.7,0)
   \begin{psclip}%
 {\psframe[linewidth=4pt,linecolor=yellow](0,29.8)(0.9,0)}
  \psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradend=cyan!70!black!40,gradbegin=black!80,linewidth=0pt](0,29.8)(0.9,0)
%
\rput{5}(-0.3,25.5){%
\scalebox{0.4}{%
  \rput(3.75,5.5){$\scriptstyle H$}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](2,0)(3.5,2.5)(3.5,5.5)(2,3)
  \psline[linecolor=magenta](0,2)(2,2)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt,linecolor=magenta](2,2)(2.75,2)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2,.75)(3.5,3.25)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2.75,1.25)(2.75,4.25)
  \psline[linecolor=magenta](2.75,2)(5,2)
  \rput(5.25,2){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \psdot[dotsize=0.1](2.75,2)
  \rput(3,1.7){$\scriptstyle A$}
    \rput(1.5,3.75){$\textcolor{red}{\scriptstyle\vv{v}}$}
  \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(2.75,2)(3.75,2)
  \rput(3.5,2.25){$\textcolor{blue}{\scriptstyle \vv{u}=\vv{n}_H}$}
   \psdot[dotsize=0.1](2.75,2)
  %\psdot(2.0,0.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan](0,3.5)(2.3,3.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan,linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2.3,3.5)(2.75,3.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan](2.75,3.5)(5,3.5)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2,2.25)(3.5,4.75)
   \rput(1,3.75){$\scriptstyle B$}
  \rput(5.25,3.5){$\scriptstyle h$}
  \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1,3.5)(2,3.5)
   \psdot(1,3.5)
  \psdot(2.75,3.5)
  \rput(3,3.2){$\scriptstyle F$}
  \pnode(0,2){X}
\pnode(2.75,2){A}
\pnode(2,0.75){Y}
\pnode(2.75,3.5){D}
\pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue!50, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=.5]{X}{A}{Y}
\pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue!50, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=.4]{D}{A}{X}
}}
%
\rput{65}(0.55,22.5){%
\scalebox{1.2}{%
\textcolor{gray!80}{$E_1\cap E_2=\{g\}$}
}}
%
\rput{30}(0.2,18){%
\scalebox{.5}{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.6](0,1)(2,1)(3,2)(1,2)(0,1)
  \psline(0,0.5)(0.75,1)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](0.75,1)(1.5,1.5)
  \psline(1.5,1.5)(3,2.5)
  \psdot(1.5,1.5)
  \rput(3.25,2.5){$g$}
  \rput(1.25,1.6){$S$}
  \rput(2.5,1){$E$}
}}
\rput{80}(0.5,15){%
\scalebox{.75}{%
$\vv{u}\circ\vv*{n}{E}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  7 \\
  2
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
  -2 \\
  7
\end{pmatrix}=0  $
}}
\rput{-20}(-1.1,9.5){%
\scalebox{.7}{%
\pnode(2.75,1.5){A}
\pnode(1.75,1.5){B}
\pnode(1.75,2.75){C}
\pnode(0.75,2.75){D}
\pnode(0.75,1.5){E}
\pnode(1.25,3.25){F}
\pnode(1.25,2.0){G}
\pnode(1.75,2.95){H}
\pnode(1.25,2.0){I}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](0,1)(2.5,1)(3.5,2)(1,2)
  \pcline(B)(C)
  \nbput[npos=0.48,labelsep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle d$}
  \pstThreeDEllipse[beginAngle=0,endAngle=-90](-0.77,1.7,3.67)(0,-0.3,0)(0,0,0.45)
  \uput{0.08}[200](C){\psdot[dotsize=0.05](0,0)}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](0,2.25)(2.5,2.25)(3.5,3.25)(1,3.25)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.08,linecolor=blue](1.25,1)(B)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.05,linecolor=red](F)(C)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.08,linecolor=red!50,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 1pt](1.25,2)(B)
  \pstThreeDEllipse[beginAngle=90,endAngle=0](-0.77,1.7,1.99)(0.3,0,0)(0,0,0.4)
  \uput{0.08}[160](B){\psdot[dotsize=0.05](0,0)}
  \rput(2.8,1.8){$\scriptstyle H$}
  \rput(1,0.8){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \rput(1.2,3.1){$\scriptstyle h$}
  \psdot[dotsize=0.08](B)
  \psdot[dotsize=0.08](C)
}}
%
\rput{-80}(0.55,6.0){%
\scalebox{0.9}{%
   $E:2x_1-3x_2+4x_3-7=0$
}}
%
\rput{15}(0.0,1){%
\scalebox{.45}{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60](0,1)(2.5,1)(3.5,2)(1,2)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!60,opacity=0.5](0.5,2.25)(1.5,3.25)(3,0.75)(2,-0.25)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60,opacity=0.5](2.25,2)(3.5,2)(2.5,1)(1.25,1)
  \pcline[nodesep=-0.4](1.25,1)(2.25,2)
  \psline[linestyle=solid](2.72,1.22)(2.5,1)(1.25,1)
  \psline[linestyle=solid](2.72,1.22)(3,0.75)(2,-0.25)(0.5,2.25)(1.5,3.25)(2.25,2)
  \rput[l](2.6,2.3){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \rput[l](1.9,0.2){$\scriptstyle E_{2}$}
  \rput[l](0.6,1.2){$\scriptstyle E_{1}$}
}}
\end{psclip}
}}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.9cm}%
\footskip=8mm
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.9cm} \textheight26.5cm \textwidth18.0cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Test}
\rhead{Geometrie}
\rfoot{\makebox[0mm][l]{\hspace*{-5mm}\setlength\fboxsep{3pt}\fcolorbox{black!90}{black!90}{\makebox[75pt]{\hfill%
\textcolor{cyan!20}{Seite~\thepage \hspace*{1.4cm}}}}}}
\cfoot{}

\parindent0pt
\parskip4pt



\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Titelseite}{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{3.5cm} \DeclareFixedFont{\Rm}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{2mm}
\psset{shadow=true,blur=true,shadowsize=10pt,blurradius=5pt,blurbg=blue!10}
\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,3.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=blue,slopeend=magenta} \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\pscharpath{\RM MATHE}}
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,3.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=black!80!green!60,slopeend=yellow} \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\pscharpath{\RM Oberstufe}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,4.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=magenta,slopeend=blue} \rput(0.5\linewidth,1.75cm){\pscharpath{\RM Kompakt}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-3cm)(\linewidth,4)
\DeclareFixedFont{\SF}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{4.5cm}%
\psset{linestyle=none,linecolor=red,linewidth=0pt}
 \pstextpath[l](-1ex,-1ex){\pscustom{%
\psplot[plotpoints=200,linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=red,linestyle=none]{0}{16}%
{x 180 mul 3.1415926 div cos 2 mul 1 add}%
 }}{%
\color{blue} Ich bin ein Sinus!  Nein, ein Komplementi Sinus? Also ein Tangens bin ich sicher nicht und auch
kein Schaubild einer e-Funktion, soviel ist sicher. Hi Hi Hi Am besten ich schau mal im entsprechenden
Kapitel nach. sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder
cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus?
}
\end{pspicture}


 Thomas Söll %\index[name]{Söll, Thomas}\index[name]{Ossig, Uli}\index[name]{Söll, Anna}
 \vspace*{1cm} \\
 Rhön-Gymnasium-Gymnasium \\
 in \\
 Bad Neustadt

\Acrobatmenu{GeneralInfo}{\fbox{DokumentInfo}}

 \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

Hier steht noch immer der gleiche Text, aber jetzt auf der zweiten Seite.

\end{document}
```

Comment: YES! :-) finally I use a converter to EPS (there are converters on-line an use the first post \incgraph[paper=document][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cover-test.eps} and perfect!! ) and your quality solutions´re going to be in consideration for any other things and make prettier job. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of your picture should obviously match the ratio of your document. The pixel dimensions to use depend on the purpose of the resulting document: for an online document a small dpi will do; for a high quality print your will need a higher dpi value.

If `pdflatex` is your compiler, you could use the following code to include your image as cover without margins using the `incgraph` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{incgraph}

\begin{document}

% Cover picture
\incgraph[paper=document][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}

% Rest of document
\chapter{My first chapter}

Bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Alternative:**

Create you document with PSTricks. Maybe, you want to insert a dummy cover page, if page numbering should start with the cover.
Then, compile with `latex` and convert the result into a PDF file, let's say `yourdocument.pdf`.

Finally, merge your `cover.jpg` with `yourdocument.pdf` by the following code (compilable with `pdflatex`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{incgraph,pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\incgraph[paper=document][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cover.jpg}
\includepdf[pages={2-}]{yourdocument.pdf}%  dummy cover removed
\end{document}
```

Comment: @thomas-f-sturm I use LATEX, not PDFLatex, because I use PSTricks, but... It´s ok. Only one thing, after put \include{incgraph} the compilingn give error with \usepackage{mathpazo}... that was avoided with x11name option in global options

Comment: I try your code and go well!!!  but when I use my cover-test.jpg using LATEX.  I had no success including my test-cover https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap60m8p7etqoxyc/cover-test.jpg

Comment: If PDFLaTeX is no option because of using PSTricks, you cannot use my answer directly. `incgraph` needs PDFLaTeX. But, if your final document is a PDF file, you could use the `pdfpages` package to merge the your cover image with your final document into a really-final-document.

Comment: @MikaIke I extended my answer with a suggestion how to insert the cover image finally into your document.

Answer (score 2):

I used the package `eso-pic`, then you can insert your `pstricks` graphics as in the example.

[image]

If you write `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` without the star, the picture is on every page.

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
\psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradmidpoint=0.9,gradend=cyan!30!black!20,gradbegin=black!10,linewidth=0pt](0.7,0)(21,29.8)
%\psline[linecolor=yellow,linewidth=1.5pt](20.7,29.8)(20.7,0)
   \begin{psclip}%
 {\psframe[linewidth=4pt,linecolor=yellow](0,29.8)(0.9,0)}
  \psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradend=cyan!70!black!40,gradbegin=black!80,linewidth=0pt](0,29.8)(0.9,0)
%
\rput{5}(-0.3,25.5){%
\scalebox{0.4}{%
  \rput(3.75,5.5){$\scriptstyle H$}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](2,0)(3.5,2.5)(3.5,5.5)(2,3)
  \psline[linecolor=magenta](0,2)(2,2)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt,linecolor=magenta](2,2)(2.75,2)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2,.75)(3.5,3.25)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2.75,1.25)(2.75,4.25)
  \psline[linecolor=magenta](2.75,2)(5,2)
  \rput(5.25,2){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \psdot[dotsize=0.1](2.75,2)
  \rput(3,1.7){$\scriptstyle A$}
    \rput(1.5,3.75){$\textcolor{red}{\scriptstyle\vv{v}}$}
  \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(2.75,2)(3.75,2)
  \rput(3.5,2.25){$\textcolor{blue}{\scriptstyle \vv{u}=\vv{n}_H}$}
   \psdot[dotsize=0.1](2.75,2)
  %\psdot(2.0,0.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan](0,3.5)(2.3,3.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan,linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2.3,3.5)(2.75,3.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan](2.75,3.5)(5,3.5)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2,2.25)(3.5,4.75)
   \rput(1,3.75){$\scriptstyle B$}
  \rput(5.25,3.5){$\scriptstyle h$}
  \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1,3.5)(2,3.5)
   \psdot(1,3.5)
  \psdot(2.75,3.5)
  \rput(3,3.2){$\scriptstyle F$}
  \pnode(0,2){X}
\pnode(2.75,2){A}
\pnode(2,0.75){Y}
\pnode(2.75,3.5){D}
\pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue!50, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=.5]{X}{A}{Y}
\pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue!50, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=.4]{D}{A}{X}
}}
%
\rput{65}(0.55,22.5){%
\scalebox{1.2}{%
\textcolor{gray!80}{$E_1\cap E_2=\{g\}$}
}}
%
\rput{30}(0.2,18){%
\scalebox{.5}{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.6](0,1)(2,1)(3,2)(1,2)(0,1)
  \psline(0,0.5)(0.75,1)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](0.75,1)(1.5,1.5)
  \psline(1.5,1.5)(3,2.5)
  \psdot(1.5,1.5)
  \rput(3.25,2.5){$g$}
  \rput(1.25,1.6){$S$}
  \rput(2.5,1){$E$}
}}
\rput{80}(0.5,15){%
\scalebox{.75}{%
$\vv{u}\circ\vv*{n}{E}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  7 \\
  2
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
  -2 \\
  7
\end{pmatrix}=0  $
}}
\rput{-20}(-1.1,9.5){%
\scalebox{.7}{%
\pnode(2.75,1.5){A}
\pnode(1.75,1.5){B}
\pnode(1.75,2.75){C}
\pnode(0.75,2.75){D}
\pnode(0.75,1.5){E}
\pnode(1.25,3.25){F}
\pnode(1.25,2.0){G}
\pnode(1.75,2.95){H}
\pnode(1.25,2.0){I}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](0,1)(2.5,1)(3.5,2)(1,2)
  \pcline(B)(C)
  \nbput[npos=0.48,labelsep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle d$}
  \pstThreeDEllipse[beginAngle=0,endAngle=-90](-0.77,1.7,3.67)(0,-0.3,0)(0,0,0.45)
  \uput{0.08}[200](C){\psdot[dotsize=0.05](0,0)}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](0,2.25)(2.5,2.25)(3.5,3.25)(1,3.25)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.08,linecolor=blue](1.25,1)(B)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.05,linecolor=red](F)(C)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.08,linecolor=red!50,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 1pt](1.25,2)(B)
  \pstThreeDEllipse[beginAngle=90,endAngle=0](-0.77,1.7,1.99)(0.3,0,0)(0,0,0.4)
  \uput{0.08}[160](B){\psdot[dotsize=0.05](0,0)}
  \rput(2.8,1.8){$\scriptstyle H$}
  \rput(1,0.8){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \rput(1.2,3.1){$\scriptstyle h$}
  \psdot[dotsize=0.08](B)
  \psdot[dotsize=0.08](C)
}}
%
\rput{-80}(0.55,6.0){%
\scalebox{0.9}{%
   $E:2x_1-3x_2+4x_3-7=0$
}}
%
\rput{15}(0.0,1){%
\scalebox{.45}{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60](0,1)(2.5,1)(3.5,2)(1,2)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!60,opacity=0.5](0.5,2.25)(1.5,3.25)(3,0.75)(2,-0.25)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60,opacity=0.5](2.25,2)(3.5,2)(2.5,1)(1.25,1)
  \pcline[nodesep=-0.4](1.25,1)(2.25,2)
  \psline[linestyle=solid](2.72,1.22)(2.5,1)(1.25,1)
  \psline[linestyle=solid](2.72,1.22)(3,0.75)(2,-0.25)(0.5,2.25)(1.5,3.25)(2.25,2)
  \rput[l](2.6,2.3){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \rput[l](1.9,0.2){$\scriptstyle E_{2}$}
  \rput[l](0.6,1.2){$\scriptstyle E_{1}$}
}}
\end{psclip}
}}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.9cm}%
\footskip=8mm
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.9cm} \textheight26.5cm \textwidth18.0cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Test}
\rhead{Geometrie}
\rfoot{\makebox[0mm][l]{\hspace*{-5mm}\setlength\fboxsep{3pt}\fcolorbox{black!90}{black!90}{\makebox[75pt]{\hfill%
\textcolor{white}{Seite~\thepage \hspace*{1.4cm}}}}}}
\cfoot{}

\parindent0pt
\parskip4pt



\begin{document}

Hier steht der Text

\newpage

Hier steht noch immer der gleiche Text, aber jetzt auf der zweiten Seite.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like very much your job :-) In this case I prefer use una .jpg iage to insert as cover page ( similar to https://www.dropbox.com/s/ap60m8p7etqoxyc/cover-test.jpg I want to use Fireworks with many images.

Comment: have you more examples? :-) I like it very much. Is possible you share any other examples?

Answer (score 2):

With more feeling like a coverpage
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[b]{esvect}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-grad}
\usepackage[tiling]{pst-fill}
\usepackage{pst-text}
\usepackage{pst-slpe}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{%
pagecolor=blue, menucolor=blue, linkcolor=blue,
bookmarksopen=true, % Anzeige aller Ebenen
bookmarksnumbered=true, % Anzeige der Abschnittsnummern
pdfstartpage={}, % Startseite
pdfstartview={FitH}, % Legt die Anzeigegröße fest
pdftitle = {Mathematik in Klasse 12}, 
pdfsubject = {Unterrichtsmaterial},
pdfauthor = {Söll, Thomas} }

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
\psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradmidpoint=0.9,gradend=cyan!30!black!20,gradbegin=black!10,linewidth=0pt](0.7,0)(21,29.8)
%\psline[linecolor=yellow,linewidth=1.5pt](20.7,29.8)(20.7,0)
   \begin{psclip}%
 {\psframe[linewidth=4pt,linecolor=yellow](0,29.8)(0.9,0)}
  \psframe[linestyle=none,fillstyle=gradient,gradangle=0,gradend=cyan!70!black!40,gradbegin=black!80,linewidth=0pt](0,29.8)(0.9,0)
%
\rput{5}(-0.3,25.5){%
\scalebox{0.4}{%
  \rput(3.75,5.5){$\scriptstyle H$}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](2,0)(3.5,2.5)(3.5,5.5)(2,3)
  \psline[linecolor=magenta](0,2)(2,2)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt,linecolor=magenta](2,2)(2.75,2)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2,.75)(3.5,3.25)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2.75,1.25)(2.75,4.25)
  \psline[linecolor=magenta](2.75,2)(5,2)
  \rput(5.25,2){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \psdot[dotsize=0.1](2.75,2)
  \rput(3,1.7){$\scriptstyle A$}
    \rput(1.5,3.75){$\textcolor{red}{\scriptstyle\vv{v}}$}
  \psline[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(2.75,2)(3.75,2)
  \rput(3.5,2.25){$\textcolor{blue}{\scriptstyle \vv{u}=\vv{n}_H}$}
   \psdot[dotsize=0.1](2.75,2)
  %\psdot(2.0,0.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan](0,3.5)(2.3,3.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan,linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2.3,3.5)(2.75,3.5)
  \psline[linecolor=cyan](2.75,3.5)(5,3.5)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted,dotsep=1pt](2,2.25)(3.5,4.75)
   \rput(1,3.75){$\scriptstyle B$}
  \rput(5.25,3.5){$\scriptstyle h$}
  \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=1.5pt]{->}(1,3.5)(2,3.5)
   \psdot(1,3.5)
  \psdot(2.75,3.5)
  \rput(3,3.2){$\scriptstyle F$}
  \pnode(0,2){X}
\pnode(2.75,2){A}
\pnode(2,0.75){Y}
\pnode(2.75,3.5){D}
\pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue!50, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=.5]{X}{A}{Y}
\pstRightAngle[linecolor=blue!50, RightAngleType=german,RightAngleSize=.4]{D}{A}{X}
}}
%
\rput{65}(0.55,22.5){%
\scalebox{1.2}{%
\textcolor{gray!80}{$E_1\cap E_2=\{g\}$}
}}
%
\rput{30}(0.2,18){%
\scalebox{.5}{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,opacity=0.6](0,1)(2,1)(3,2)(1,2)(0,1)
  \psline(0,0.5)(0.75,1)
  \psline[linestyle=dotted](0.75,1)(1.5,1.5)
  \psline(1.5,1.5)(3,2.5)
  \psdot(1.5,1.5)
  \rput(3.25,2.5){$g$}
  \rput(1.25,1.6){$S$}
  \rput(2.5,1){$E$}
}}
\rput{80}(0.5,15){%
\scalebox{.75}{%
$\vv{u}\circ\vv*{n}{E}=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  7 \\
  2
\end{pmatrix}\circ\begin{pmatrix}
  3 \\
  -2 \\
  7
\end{pmatrix}=0  $
}}
\rput{-20}(-1.1,9.5){%
\scalebox{.7}{%
\pnode(2.75,1.5){A}
\pnode(1.75,1.5){B}
\pnode(1.75,2.75){C}
\pnode(0.75,2.75){D}
\pnode(0.75,1.5){E}
\pnode(1.25,3.25){F}
\pnode(1.25,2.0){G}
\pnode(1.75,2.95){H}
\pnode(1.25,2.0){I}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](0,1)(2.5,1)(3.5,2)(1,2)
  \pcline(B)(C)
  \nbput[npos=0.48,labelsep=1pt]{$\scriptstyle d$}
  \pstThreeDEllipse[beginAngle=0,endAngle=-90](-0.77,1.7,3.67)(0,-0.3,0)(0,0,0.45)
  \uput{0.08}[200](C){\psdot[dotsize=0.05](0,0)}
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,opacity=0.5](0,2.25)(2.5,2.25)(3.5,3.25)(1,3.25)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.08,linecolor=blue](1.25,1)(B)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.05,linecolor=red](F)(C)
  \pcline[nodesepB=-0.8,nodesepA=-0.08,linecolor=red!50,linestyle=dashed,dash=2pt 1pt](1.25,2)(B)
  \pstThreeDEllipse[beginAngle=90,endAngle=0](-0.77,1.7,1.99)(0.3,0,0)(0,0,0.4)
  \uput{0.08}[160](B){\psdot[dotsize=0.05](0,0)}
  \rput(2.8,1.8){$\scriptstyle H$}
  \rput(1,0.8){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \rput(1.2,3.1){$\scriptstyle h$}
  \psdot[dotsize=0.08](B)
  \psdot[dotsize=0.08](C)
}}
%
\rput{-80}(0.55,6.0){%
\scalebox{0.9}{%
   $E:2x_1-3x_2+4x_3-7=0$
}}
%
\rput{15}(0.0,1){%
\scalebox{.45}{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60](0,1)(2.5,1)(3.5,2)(1,2)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!60,opacity=0.5](0.5,2.25)(1.5,3.25)(3,0.75)(2,-0.25)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!60,opacity=0.5](2.25,2)(3.5,2)(2.5,1)(1.25,1)
  \pcline[nodesep=-0.4](1.25,1)(2.25,2)
  \psline[linestyle=solid](2.72,1.22)(2.5,1)(1.25,1)
  \psline[linestyle=solid](2.72,1.22)(3,0.75)(2,-0.25)(0.5,2.25)(1.5,3.25)(2.25,2)
  \rput[l](2.6,2.3){$\scriptstyle g$}
  \rput[l](1.9,0.2){$\scriptstyle E_{2}$}
  \rput[l](0.6,1.2){$\scriptstyle E_{1}$}
}}
\end{psclip}
}}


\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.9cm}%
\footskip=8mm
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.9cm} \textheight26.5cm \textwidth18.0cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Test}
\rhead{Geometrie}
\rfoot{\makebox[0mm][l]{\hspace*{-5mm}\setlength\fboxsep{3pt}\fcolorbox{black!90}{black!90}{\makebox[75pt]{\hfill%
\textcolor{cyan!20}{Seite~\thepage \hspace*{1.4cm}}}}}}
\cfoot{}

\parindent0pt
\parskip4pt



\begin{document}

\pdfbookmark[0]{Titelseite}{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}
\DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{ptm}{b}{n}{3.5cm} \DeclareFixedFont{\Rm}{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}{2mm}
\psset{shadow=true,blur=true,shadowsize=10pt,blurradius=5pt,blurbg=blue!10}
\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,3.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=blue,slopeend=magenta} \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\pscharpath{\RM MATHE}}
\end{pspicture}


\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,3.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=black!80!green!60,slopeend=yellow} \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\pscharpath{\RM Oberstufe}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(\linewidth,4.5cm)
\psset{fillstyle=slope,slopebegin=magenta,slopeend=blue} \rput(0.5\linewidth,1.75cm){\pscharpath{\RM Kompakt}}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(0,-3cm)(\linewidth,4)
\DeclareFixedFont{\SF}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{4.5cm}%
\psset{linestyle=none,linecolor=red,linewidth=0pt}
 \pstextpath[l](-1ex,-1ex){\pscustom{%
\psplot[plotpoints=200,linewidth=1.5pt, linecolor=red,linestyle=none]{0}{16}%
{x 180 mul 3.1415926 div cos 2 mul 1 add}%
 }}{%
\color{blue} Ich bin ein Sinus!  Nein, ein Komplementi Sinus? Also ein Tangens bin ich sicher nicht und auch
kein Schaubild einer e-Funktion, soviel ist sicher. Hi Hi Hi Am besten ich schau mal im entsprechenden
Kapitel nach. sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder
cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus? sinus oder cosinus?
}
\end{pspicture}


 Thomas Söll %\index[name]{Söll, Thomas}\index[name]{Ossig, Uli}\index[name]{Söll, Anna}
 \vspace*{1cm} \\
 Rhön-Gymnasium-Gymnasium \\
 in \\
 Bad Neustadt

\Acrobatmenu{GeneralInfo}{\fbox{DokumentInfo}}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

Hier steht noch immer der gleiche Text, aber jetzt auf der zweiten Seite.

\end{document}
```